# Transfering NSString from prototype cell not working with prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am just trying to transfer a simple string from a UILabel in a prototype cell into a label in the next View Controller. Value of label.text in the viewDidLoad of the View Controller is returning (null).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    mainCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (mainCell == nil) {
        mainCell = [[dictionaryTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString* date = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mainCell.viewLabel.text = date;

    return mainCell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"View Segue"]) {
        NSLog(@"View Load Segue Success");

        ViewController *one = segue.destinationViewController;
        one.label.text = mainCell.viewLabel.text;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexPathForSelectedRow`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"View Segue"]) {

        ViewController *one = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        one.textProperty = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Or you can also use `sender` if your segue is from the cell to the next scene, e.g.:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"View Segue"])
    {
        ViewController *one = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSAssert([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]], @"Not cell");

        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        one.textProperty = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

1. As a matter of good programming style, I am not retrieving the text value from the cell. I'm retrieving the text value from the model. You should not be relying upon the view for information to be passed along. Go back to the model, the original source of the information.
2. Do not set the `text` property of the `label` in the destination controller directly. The controls of the `destinationController` have not been created yet. You should defer setting controls until the `destinationController`'s `viewDidLoad`. So, instead, create a `NSString` property in the destination controller:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textProperty;
   ```

   Clearly, you should use a more descriptive name than `textProperty`, but hopefully you get the idea. Anyway, `prepareForSegue` can set this new property and the `viewDidLoad` of the destination controller should then use that `NSString` property to populate the `text` property of the `UILabel`, e.g.:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       self.label.text = self.textProperty;
   }
   ```

Comment: Makes logical sense. I tried the first way and I got the first error though asking if I meant segue.destinationViewController and then got the next error after that saying "No known instance method for selector 'setTextProperty:' @Rob

Comment: when I tried to compile and run on the simulator it came up with Build Failed and gave me that error

Comment: @Zack Assuming that `ViewController` is the class name for your destination controller, you can use that. See my updated answer. (By the way, `ViewController` is a curious name for the destination controller. That's usually the name of the first view controller in standard Xcode projects, which are generally not destinations for segues.)

Comment: Got it to work thanks a million! and btw I just changed the name to ViewController. It is not physically called that in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"View Segue"]) {
        NSLog(@"View Load Segue Success");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ViewController *one = segue.destinationViewController;
        one.label.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

And actually, assigning text to text label you should do in your viewController `one`'s method(`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`). So, you need to make a property in viewController one for transferring `NSString`.

Comment: `indexPathForSelectedRow` great!

Comment: @Flink Alright so I tried what you did above and it still does not work. However I am still trying to understand what you mean by the second part. Do you mind showing me an example of what I should do?

Comment: @Zack Check this http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1.

Comment: By property I mean: @property (nonatomic) NSString *dateString;

Comment: @Zack Don't try to set the `text` property of the `label` in the destination controller. It hasn't been created yet. Thus `one.label.text = ...` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
    YourViewController *controller =[[YourViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    one.label.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Change the `label.text` after `presentModalViewController`. Now what happens?

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

I understand you are already using `Segue`. You should follow the other answer.

Comment: dateArray has multiple objects though i.e. Cats, Dogs. Not just one. That obviously will pull the first one in the set (Cats) but if I select the cell with the value (Dogs) in the text it will still return Cats. Also the one.label.text is still returning null for some reason

Comment: Still returning null. "/ I have no idea why. You want me to allocate the View Controller in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath correct?

Comment: presentModalViewController: is deprecated.

Comment: @Zack This can work, use presentViewController and put 'one.label.text = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];' into completion

Comment: @Fink but which way is I guess the more proper way?